# Mongoose Query Where Clause with Wildcard

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a mongoose query as the below

```
Computer
    .find()
    .where('OS').equals('Windows')
    .exec(function(err, items) {

  });
```

It returns all `computer` records with `Windows` OS.

Now I want to use a **variable** `osType` to replace the `equals` parameter to be more flexible.

Can I supply a wildcard `*` to the `osType` variable? I tested it and it is not working.

```
var osType = '*';

Computer
    .find()
    .where('OS').equals(osType)
    .exec(function(err, items) {

  });
```

Or what are the alternatives to achieve this?

Please do not delete the `where` clause as I want it to be used for `osType=windows, linux ...` etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're going to have to switch between these two statements:

```
// If you have a specific value you want to find:
Computer.find().where('OS').equals(osType).exec(...)
```

And:

```
// All documents that have a `OS` property:
Computer.find().where('OS').exists().exec(...)
```

You can rewrite your code to accommodate for that:

```
var query = Computer.find().where('OS');
if (osType === '*') {
  query = query.exists();
} else {
  query = query.equals(osType);
}
query.exec(...);
```

Alternatively, you could use [`Query#regex`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-regex) to fold both query types into one, but I expect this will have a performance impact.

Comment: if I am using `Query#regex`, can I use wildcard `*` to indicate it matches all strings for `osType` field? If not, how can I use something to indicate **match all**

Comment: `.*` means "match all" in regular expressions (I think that in Mongoose it will become `Computer.find().where('OS').regex(/.*/).exec(...)`

Comment: I have put a variable `osType = new RegExp('.*')` and used `where('OS').regex(osType).exec(...)` to make it work. thank you for providing the regex solution.